# Using Regular Expressions with DownThemAll to exclude a file name

Tags: regex, download-manager

I'm using DownThemAll and a bit of regex to grab files from a web page.

My DownThemAll filter is set up as follows: `/\.(?:pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|zip)$/i`

However, each page also includes the file WBSDictionary.xls, which I'd like to exclude.

I've tried `/(?!WBSDictionary)\.(?:pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|zip)$/i` to no avail. Am I doing it wrong, or does DTA's implementation of regex simply not support this?

I'm pretty new to regex.

Answer (score 3):

Try this include files with extensions `pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|zip` while excluding the file `WBSDictionary.xls`

```
/^(?!.*WBSDictionary\.xls$).*\.(pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|zip)$/i
```

Hope that helps